# Mathematica Basic Plotting Question

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to plot `y = x^2` and `x = y^2` on the some graph? For some reason, I can't get it to plot the `x = y^2` properly. Here is what I get:

```
Show[{ Plot[x == y^2, {y, -1, 1}], Plot[y = x^2, {x, -1, 1}]}]
```

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you just have to change how you think about plotting, a little. Specifically, you are looking for [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricPlot.html).

```
ParametricPlot[{{t, t^2}, {t^2, t}}, {t, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is good to see. Thank you!

Comment: Just wondering, is it possible to fill in the enclosed region?

Comment: @spryno724, that requires an entirely different approach... `RegionPlot[x^2 < y && y^2 < x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Ah... ok. Just thought I would check.

Answer (score 4):

rcollyer's method is the best way of going about it. Here's an alternative:

```
g = Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}];
Show[g, g /. v_ /; VectorQ[v, NumericQ] && Length[v] == 2 :> Reverse[v], 
     PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: parabolas]

Here's a more conventional route, tho:

```
ContourPlot[{y == x^2, x == y^2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False]
```

[image: parabolas, again]

To see the filled version being asked in the comments:

```
Show[ContourPlot[{y == x^2, x == y^2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], 
     RegionPlot[x^2 < y && y^2 < x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}],
     Axes -> True, Frame -> False]
```

[image: parabolas with filling]

Answer (score 4):

For completeness we can mention finding all branches of inverse function. It won't always work, but it is conceptually instructive for simple cases.

```
f[x_] = x^2; g[x_] = InverseFunction[f][x]
```

> -Sqrt[x]

```
Plot[{f[x], g[x], -g[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, Filling -> {1 -> {3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: `ParametricPlot` needs `Filling` as an option! :)

Comment: @rcollyer: orienting the filling would be a bit problematic, tho...

Comment: @rcollyer MeshShading as a remedy ;)

Comment: @J.M. maybe. But, filling between lines would be less difficult.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov why yes it is, but I'll have to play with that tomorrow.